# Photoshop - Save batch process

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-action

In photoshop, I recently learned how to create actions, and how to do them in batches (for example, execute them on a folder of 1000 files).

What I need to know is this: How can I SAVE THE BATCH PROCESS? I need to save all the settings with which I perform the batch process, so I can easily perform the exact same batch process, again.

Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you recorded an action then it's already saved. You can also create a Droplet from File > Automate

Comment: I'm looking to save the Batch, not the action. So all the settings in the batch process.

Comment: Oh. That's what a droplet is, isn't it? An executable batch... Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.                        


Here's some more characters to meet the 15 character requirement.